firebase GCP - Firestore Maintenance
How and when does Google provision Maintenance on the firestore database?
And is there any audit logs for it? Or how notifications can be enabled?
Trying to check the Maintenance Schedule of Google on Firestore and did not find any answers on it on any forums

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Firestore (like many Google Cloud Platform services) has never in its life had downtime for scheduled maintenance.
